# Many-to-many relations to itself with Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping

I have a data model that contains persons and companies (amongst other things). I have created a many-to-many relation between them by creating an intermediate object PersonCompanyRelation that contains many-to-one relations to person and companies. The reason for this is that I want to store information about the relation. This works fine

Now I want to do the same but for linking persons to persons. I have again created a relationship object called PersonPersonRelation. The problem I run into is that in the Person object I have to specify what property the object is mapped to in the relationship object, however this is problematic since it will differ from relationship to relationship. Sometimes this will be A, sometimes it will be B. It doesn't matter which one it is but without a logical system I cannot logically retrieve the relations. How do I do this?

the code in PersonPersonRelation

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="personPersonRelations")
 */
protected $personA;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Person", inversedBy="personPersonRelations")
 */
protected $personB;
```

the code in Person. Note how I need to specify the property in the relation it is mapped to, but from the perspective of Person I do not know whether this will be PersonA or PersonB

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonPersonRelation", mappedBy="personA")
 */
protected $personPersonRelations;
```

To clarify as asked below; The case is that I want to store professional relations between people, including details about that relation like how they met (colleagues, friends, family etc) as well as dates etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure that if you specify less generic names, all should be more clear.

Just to make and example, let's say that Person-Person relationship is a relation between Boss and Employee.

So, basically, every person will have two attributes

```
class Person
{
  //other properties

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="person", mappedBy="employees")
   */
  $boss;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="person", inversedBy="boss")
   */
  $employees;
}
```

If I understood correctly the question, in every moment, you can alternatively try to retrieve:

- from a boss-person point of view, all employees under him
- from a employee-person point of view, its boss

Of course mine is only an example, don't know if you could fit your mind in it to adapt to your specific case. Hope so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The relation really is equal. In this particular case I want to register a person's professional network. Along with this relation I want to store how they met. This can be as colleagues, but also friends, family, unknown, etc.

Comment: So from the point of view of the Person entity, I can't figure out a way to logically store the reference to the person in the PersonRelation in either personA or personB (and be able to retrieve that logically)